# css selector for selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, xpath, css-selectors

I want to get text from below code. Here I want to copy `.js_count` class text result.

```
<div class="search-result-bar">
    <div class="search-result-bar-country">
        <a class="search-result-bar-country-title" href="javascript:void(0);" title="paris">paris </a>
        <span class="search-result-bar-country-dot">
        ·
        </span>
        <span class="search-result-bar-country-count">
            <span class="js_count">10146</span>
            <span class="js_text"> rentals</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error Log:

```
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=span.js_count} at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Nativ‌​e Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknow‌​n Source) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Un‌​known Source) at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createE‌xception(W3CHttpResp‌​onseCodec.java:133)
```

Comment: try xpath `"//span[@class='js_count']"`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below `XPath` expression

```
//span[@class="js_count"]
```

or `CSS` selector

```
span.js_count
```

to locate required element and then use `getText()` method to extract its text content

Comment: I tried with css selector but always getting this error
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=span.js_count}
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
 at

Comment: Use `Edit` option to update your ticket with selectors you've already tried and error log